# `attr('checked', false)` not working on IE6

Tags: javascript, jquery

As the title says, I can't get `.attr('checked', false)` to work on IE6. I am cloning some HTML and then before I assign the newly cloned HTML to a element, I run through it and un-check all of the checkboxes that are in the newly cloned section, which works fine in all browsers except IE 6.

Here is the code:

```
    //give each input and select a custom id
    clone.find('input, select').each( function( i ) {

            //get the id attribute
            var id = $(this).attr('id');

            //uncheck all of the tick boxes
            $(this).attr('checked', '');

            //get the name attribute
            var name = $(this).attr('name');

            $(this).attr('name', name+"_"+count)
            $(this).attr('id', id+"_"+count+"_"+i)

    });

    //append the newly created area to the area wrapper
    clone.appendTo('[data-custom="area_wrapper"]');
```

Is there any way that I can work around this problem?

Comment: In your code you use `attr('checked', '')`, does this not work either?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
.removeAttr("checked")
```

Comment: Try? Are you not confident that it will work? Could it be that no-one really knows what jQuery's `attr()` and related methods are actually supposed to do?

Answer (score 7):

The simplest solution is also an optimisation:

```
this.checked = false;
```

In fact, you can apply this optimisation to all of your code:

```
        //get the id attribute
        var id = this.id;

        //uncheck all of the tick boxes
        this.checked = false;

        //get the name attribute
        var name = this.name;

        this.name = name+"_"+count;
        this.id = id+"_"+count+"_"+i;
```

This is because the underlying jQuery code accesses these properties anyway (`attr` mostly works directly with properties until jQuery 1.6).

More info on this at http://whattheheadsaid.com/2010/10/utilizing-the-awesome-power-of-jquery-to-access-properties-of-an-element.

Comment: YES YES YES. Listen to this, everyone.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, will keep it in mind for future projects. Will give it a go now and report back.

Answer (score 1):

There is no HTML attribute 'checked=false', only 'checked=checked' for checked boxes and nothing for unchecked boxes.

use `.removeAttr('checked');`