# How to SET jquery .attr(), not get it

Tags: jquery

When I want to read an attribute, I use

```
$('#mydiv').attr('id');
```

How do I write to this attribute instead, so that I can change the id of the div in the markup?

Comment: You know [the jQuery API documentation](http://api.jquery.com) is pretty clear and easy to search.

Comment: @Pointy: StackOverflow is to documentation as jQuery is to javascript.

Answer (score 4):

```
$('#mydiv').attr('id', 'value');
```

take a look at the jquery documentation, http://api.jquery.com/attr/ it's well explained

Answer (score 1):

It's more efficient and more cross-browser compatible just to use the element's `id` property:

```
$("#mydiv")[0].id = "newId";
```

Even better, you could cut out jQuery altogether:

```
document.getElementById("mydiv").id = "newId";
```

Comment: I think jquery internally does this

Comment: @gov: Indeed it does, but only after going round the houses. A similar question came up earlier: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4153703/jquery-attrchecked-false-not-working-on-ie6/4153827#4153827

Comment: Ok, seriously now, I didn't see that question earlier, so I didn't plagiarize your comment. :o)

Comment: @patrick: I thought you might be referring to my comment, but hey, great minds etc.

Answer (score 0):

Include second parameter in attr call with value to set to.

```
$('#mydiv').attr('id', 'value');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#mydiv').attr('id',value);
```

Comment: value needs to be in "quotes" unless it a variable

Comment: @cube , yeah i was assuming value as dynamic parameter